# How to make a smooth transition of a 3d cube animation when you click on one of the faces?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I need to make sure that when you click on one of the faces, the cube rotates smoothly with this face and the animation stops. And when you close the face, the size gradually decreased and the animation continued. Maybe someone did something similar and share an example?

Now done only for the TOP. But how to make a smooth animation I can’t imagine.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  let cube = document.querySelector('#D3Cube');
  let side1 = document.querySelector('#side1');
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector('.closeLink');

  cube.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    cube.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  });
  cube.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    cube.style.animationPlayState = "running";
  });

  side1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    cube.classList.remove("animatCube");
    cube.classList.add("animateTop");
  });
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    cube.classList.remove("animateTop");
    cube.classList.add("animatCube");
});


});
```

```css
#wrapD3Cube {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}
#D3Cube {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 50px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.animatCube{
  animation: cube 5s linear infinite;
  transform: rotateX(-22deg) rotateY(-38deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
.animateTop{
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1.5, 1, 1.5);
}

@keyframes cube {
  100%  {  transform: rotateX(-22deg) rotateY(-398deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
}
#D3Cube > div {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.85;
}
#side1 {
  transform: rotatex(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: purple;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side2 {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #ffaf1c;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side3 {
  transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #58d568;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side4 {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #ed3030;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side5 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #1c5ffe;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side6 {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #f2f215;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapD3Cube">
  <div id="D3Cube" class="animatCube">
    <div class="slide" id="side1"><a class="closeLink" href="">x</a></div>
    <div class="slide" id="side2">2</div>
    <div class="slide" id="side3">3</div>
    <div class="slide" id="side4">4</div>
    <div class="slide" id="side5">5</div>
    <div class="slide" id="side6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, at the moment I can see that in the console there's an error, so first you need to put `let closeBtn = document.querySelector('.closeLink');` out of `$(document).ready` function

Comment: already fixed, but how to make planned transitions that’s the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking on a face, you can use `getComputedStyle(cube).getPropertyValue("transform")` to get the current state of transform when clicking on the face.
Then, you appy it in transform property to set that state, remove the animation, add the class to show the face (`animateTop`) and finally remove the inline transform you just set for the class to take effect.

When going back to normal, you remove inline stopped `animation`, some the `cube` animation will happen. After 5 seconds, the `animateTop` will be removed, then only the animation will continue to run.

I also created two variables for better control: `open` to check when the face is open or closed. And `changing` to check when it is transitioning to open or closed.

```js
let open = false;
let changing = false;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  let cube = document.querySelector('#D3Cube');
  let side1 = document.querySelector('#side1');

  side1.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (changing) {
      return;
    }

    if (!open && !changing) {

      open = true;
      changing = true;

      cube.classList.add('open')
      var compTransform = getComputedStyle(cube).getPropertyValue("transform");
      cube.style.transform = compTransform;
      cube.style.animation = 'none';
      cube.classList.add("animateTop");
      setTimeout(function() {
        cube.classList.remove('closed')
        cube.style.removeProperty('transform');
      }, 50);
      setTimeout(function() {
        changing = false;
      }, 1640);

    } else if (open && !changing) {

      open = false;
      changing = true;
      cube.classList.remove('open')
      setTimeout(function() {
        cube.classList.remove("animateTop");
        cube.classList.add('closed')
        changing = false;
      }, 4999);
      cube.style.removeProperty('animation');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapD3Cube {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 200px auto;
}
#D3Cube {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 50px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 1.64s;
}
#D3Cube.closed:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  transition: animation 0s;
}
.closeLink {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.animatCube{
  animation: cube 5s linear infinite;
  transform: rotateX(-22deg) rotateY(-38deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
.animateTop{
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1.5, 1, 1.5);
}
@keyframes cube {
  100%  {  transform: rotateX(-22deg) rotateY(-398deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
}
#D3Cube > div {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.85;
}
#side1 {
  transform: rotatex(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: purple;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side2 {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #ffaf1c;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side3 {
  transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #58d568;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side4 {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #ed3030;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side5 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #1c5ffe;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#side6 {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #f2f215;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapD3Cube">
  <div id="D3Cube" class="animatCube closed">
    <div class="slide" id="side1"><a class="closeLink" href="">X</a></div>
    <div class="slide" id="side2">2</div>
    <div class="slide" id="side3">3</div>
    <div class="slide" id="side4">4</div>
    <div class="slide" id="side5">5</div>
    <div class="slide" id="side6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: After clicking on the face again, the animation switches on further on hover. Why I don’t understand yet. Here gif.In any case, thanks.
  https://ibb.co/WWWfNMn

Comment: Did you copy all the code from my answer? I edited the CSS too.

Comment: Yes, this problem is only observed in firefox and edge. In opera and chrome, everything works fine.

Comment: I see. That's weird, I was not expecting for that. I'll try to understand and solve it later.

Comment: Edited. I fixed for Firefox. The problem was ``transition`` ``animation-play-state``. I had to use 2 extra classes now: ``open`` and ``closed`` I don't know what is happening in Edge though.